# what is the difference between an object_id, and id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

for any model instance, there is an #object_id and #id - I know that they are not the same.

However, I'm not quite sure what makes them different and how they would each be used in context.

Please help clear this up!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `:id` is the default `primary_key` of a table.And `object_id` could be the `foriegn_key` unless you set a `custom foreign_key`.

For example,take these two table `users` and `posts`.The relation would be

`user => has_many posts` and

```
post => belongs to user
```

so in the `posts` table,we should create a `foreign_key`(in this case `user_id`) to make the relations works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think this answer is not good. The @tadman one is the right one.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails, an ActiveRecord model instance has an `id` property that maps to the value stored in the `id` column of the database. This may be `nil` if the record hasn't been saved.

In Ruby, `object_id` is a value that represents the identity of the object in question. It is *always* populated with something since everything in Ruby is an object.

These two are not related. There may be several independent instances of a model, each with their own `object_id` value but an identical `id`.

If two variables refer to something with the same `object_id`, then they refer to exactly the same object.

It's rare to see `object_id` used in code, it's a Ruby internal that's hardly ever needed. Mostly it's to establish if you're talking about identical objects, or just *equivalent* ones.

You will, on the other hand, see `id` and similar values used frequently since that's the glue that holds your relational database together.

Comment: Can `id` and `object_id` be `primary` and `foreign keys` in short?

Comment: `object_id` has absolutely nothing to do with your database. It's specific to a single Ruby process and can't be expected to be anything, may as well be a unique random number. `id` on the other hand is defined by your database and is expected to be consistent over time, probably never changing. In general terms, `id` is usually your *primary key*, but something like `user_id` which refers to `users.id` could be considered a *foreign key* since it's in another table.

Answer (score 2):

Everything (and i mean everything) in Ruby is an object.  Each of these objects has an object_id, which is a value used to track them in memory, basically.

In Rails, model instances are automatically set up with methods to return their value from the corresponding column in the database.  `.id` is one of these.

As far as using in context, generally you would not use object_id in your code, ever:  it's an under-the-hood thing.

EDIT - as an aside, a common issue seen in older versions of ruby/rails (where the `object_id` method was actually called `id`, and was overridden by rail's `id` method) was caused by the fact that the object_id of `nil` is `4`.  So you would call id on a variable which you expected to be a model instance, but was actually nil, thus getting "4" back when you expected to get the id of a record from the database.

Comment: "Everything (and I mean everything) in Ruby is an object." No, not _everything_. The `end` keyword is not an object, for example. However, it's fair to say that everything _evaluates_ to an object.

Comment: @JohnFeminella Everything *evaluates to* an object might be a better way of putting this. `end` by itself isn't an object, but whatever it ends up producing as a result is guaranteed to be an object.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is specific for ActiveModel record and it relates to id column in database. `object_id` is defined on Object and is unique for every single object created in the memory.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, object was a placeholder. Consider the following, how is product_id different than product.id? Thanks!

Comment: Haha, that totally changes the character of your question!  If i was you i would delete this question and start again with a less misleading example!

Comment: @user3399101 That is total misleading!Are you actually seeking the difference between id(primary_key) and object_id(foreign_key)?

Comment: Got it! That's the answer. product.id would be the primary key whilst product_id would be a foreign key. Also, thanks Max Williams and others your answers are still useful so I won't delete this question.